# position_dodge2 does not work for multiple values in a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a *box-plot* with dodge as a position adjustment. The problem is that "position_dodge2" is not working when I use two layers of `geom_boxplot` with different data sources. An "obvious" solution is to merge both *dataframes* and then use `ggplot` with an unique *dataframe*, but I do not know how to organize the data to make it work.
The data is composed of precipitation estimation from different sources for the same location for 6 months.

```
Date        Prec1    Prec2 ...

01-01-2000  0.2      0.8   ...

.

.

.
```

Then, I used the "gather" function to create the variable precipitation in one column. Also include the month and week columns

```
Precipitation Date        Value Month Week

Prec1         01-01-2000  0.2    Jan    1

Prec2         01-01-2000  0.6    Jan    1
.
.
.
```

This is the code I have:

```
    p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Date, y=Value, group = Week), 
           position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5)) + 
           geom_boxplot(data = subset(df, Model != "PrecF1")) +
           geom_boxplot(data = subset(df, Model == "PrecF1"),
                   color = "red", 
                   width = 0.32) +
           xlab("Date") + ylab("Precipitation (mm)") +
           scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B") # adjust the x axis breaks
    
    p1 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle=0))
```

I want to compare "Prec1" values against the other estimations using *boxplots* side-by-side but `position_dodge2` does not work :(

I appreciate any help. Please let me know if I am overlooking something obvious or I should provide the data. The output is attached.
[image: Box plot image]

The data is here: [PrecData](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0vrweex10nv73t/Prec.Rda?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

Edited in the light of subsequent comments...

The problem is that you are using a continuous x axis for what is essentially a discrete set of data points, so dodging does not really make sense (as it changes the apparent date value). You can solve this by basing the x axis on as.factor(week), and fiddling the labels appropriately. Try the following...

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=as.factor(week), y=value, colour = (Model=="PrecF1"))) + 
   geom_boxplot()
```

An alternative would be to use facets.  Try the following...

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Date, y=Value, group = Week)) + 
   geom_boxplot() +
   facet_wrap(~(Model == "PrecF1")) +
   xlab("Date") + ylab("Precipitation (mm)") +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%B") + 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle=0))
```

This will give you two facets side by side, depending on whether `Model == "PrecF1"` is true or false.

Comment: By running your code suggestion, I get the boxplots in a facet mode fashion. That helps but I would like to get only one plot with the box-plots side-by-side.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  I think `geom_boxplot` uses `dodge2` by default, so the issue is really with how you are structuring the `ggplot` layers.

Comment: I agree with you @Andrew Gustar. The first alternative did not work. I just updated the post with the data.

Comment: I have had a play with it and wonder if the problem is that you are using a continuous x axis for what is essentially a discrete set of data points, so dodging does not really apply (as it changes the apparent date value). Perhaps you need to have the x axis based on `as.factor(week)`, and fiddle the labels appropriately.  Eg - try `ggplot(data = df, aes(x=as.factor(week), y=value, colour = (Model=="PrecF1"))) + geom_boxplot()`